# Why would 5G be significantly slower than 4G?

Tags: mobile-data, mobile-network, google-pixel

I have a 5g enabled Pixel 4a phone and am using it in an area with excellent T-mobile 5G coverage. For some reason when network preferences are set to 5g, the data rate is a small fraction of the speed that can be achieved when 4g is used in the same location at the same time. Could this be caused by a device defect or is there some other explanation?

Comment: Cellular networks are a shared media, so if too many users with high bandwidth demand use the same 5G cell tower segment the speed goes down. May be 4G is only used by older phones and users that don't use so much network and in the end more data transmission is left for you.

Comment: @Robert That case can be ruled out because I have another 5g device nearby that is able to get constant superfast 5g speeds.

Comment: Are you equipped to be ruling things out? 5G isn't one flavor even in the same coverage area on the same network.  Pixel 4a (non-Verizon) supports the slowest version.  What does your super-fast phone support?  You should determine the frequencies your 4a & test phones are running on for each test and record ``numbers`` to describe speeds.  *John was running very fast when a very slow car smoked him from behind*

Comment: @blindSpots yes I figured the explanation was something like that, just wanted to see if there might be some other explanation or fix. someone here knew about